# Android action bar autosrollable title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'd like to create app with `setTitle` function at `ActionBar`
But, some strings are bigger than `ActionBar` width, and i want use autoscrollable function for my title.

I try to create style for my ActionBar:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>

        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleStyle</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitleStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">1</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF64A3</item>              
    </style>
```

But it doesn't work.

Please tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: Check once by removing the `android:` namespace from your `ActionBarTitleStyle` snippet.

Comment: No, it doesn't work too :)